# Постепенное затенение в блоке с прокруткой

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть такой код - https://codepen.io/legeidaa/pen/XWjmqQx

```
<div class="stages__scroll">
                <div class="stages__scroll-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, minima mollitia totam neque cumque sint possimus quis obcaecati quae quam magnam, vel laudantium sed.</div>
                <div class="stages__scroll-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, minima mollitia totam neque cumque sint possimus quis obcaecati quae quam magnam, vel laudantium sed.</div>
                <div class="stages__scroll-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, minima mollitia totam neque cumque sint possimus quis obcaecati quae quam magnam, vel laudantium sed.</div>
                <div class="stages__scroll-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, minima mollitia totam neque cumque sint possimus quis obcaecati quae quam magnam, vel laudantium sed.</div>
                <div class="stages__scroll-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, minima mollitia totam neque cumque sint possimus quis obcaecati quae quam magnam, vel laudantium sed.</div>
                <div class="stages__scroll-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, minima mollitia totam neque cumque sint possimus quis obcaecati quae quam magnam, vel laudantium sed.</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать постепенную прозрачность scroll-item как на скриншоте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот так к примеру: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RwGWqpy

Answer (score 0):

Например в класс `stages__scroll` можно добавить это:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

Взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient